# Ionic: updating form issue

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.   I need to update records, of user.   All information of user come from DB through web-service.   It working fine and i got proper information of users when i put these information to input text-box it is not displaying values.   Then i put values like

`document.getElementById('fn').value=data[0].fname;`

By this i am able to show values in text-boxes.   When i try to post data from input i got `undefined` error.      But if i write something manually into input field i can post the value.   So how to post values without edit/change in text-box.   Please help me.

Comment: It's most likely due to that it doesn't trigger any change event when setting the value programmatically. Either you force a change event after your update, or there is a specific way of doing it in Ionic.

Comment: Thank you so much @Eric for reply as i am new to ionic frame work and unable to understand and what  is a specific way of doing it in Ionic?